# Application issues on OS X Lion

Tags: macos, glut

our application (C++ + OpenGL + GLUT)

runs OK on all Macs with 10.6.7 Snow Leopard

but we are experiencing robust problems on the OS X Lion

- application launches extremly long
- application performance was dramaticly reduced
- application craches quite often

what can be the cause of this

Comment: Lack of debugging and profiling on 10.7?

Comment: What does Instruments say (using Time Profiler, for example), when you run your application on Lion?  What are the hotspots?  When it crashes, what does your stack trace tell you about the location of the crash?  Without this kind of information, we have no chance of answering your question.

Comment: the problems were related to one uninitialized bool variable, which behaved different on Lion, than on other previous OS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was related to flaws in code... like there was an uninitialized bool variable which was initialized differently on Lion and differently on Snow Leopard